# Restarting docker engine and keeping containers running

Tags: docker

Docker 1.11 introduced modularization, and having containerd and runc responsible for the execution of containers. 

Is there any way not to stop docker engine in such a way I will be able to change the docker configuration file, but keep the containers running?

Answer (score 1):

The [blog post](https://blog.docker.com/2016/04/docker-engine-1-11-runc/) accompanying the 1.11 release states that it's a big step towards seamless Engine restarts, but inferring from the post they haven't implemented this yet.

> As an example, 1.11 is a huge step toward allowing Engine restarts/upgrades without restarting the containers, improving the availability of containers.